Test case errors for Validation Script for Emails and Passwords program
I am doing the following task:

Write a program for Master Your Credentials: A Tricky Validation Script for Emails and Passwords
Instructions

Get the input their email address
Use validate_email() to check the email format.
Get the input their password.
Use validate_password() to check the password strength.
Continue prompting and validating until both email and password are valid.

Notes

The email must have one '@' and at least one in the domain part.
validate_email() ensures the email format is correct.
The password must be at least 8 characters long.
validate_password() checks for length, digits, and letters.
The program keeps asking for input until both email and password are valid.

Sample Input:
abcd@ab.com 
password@123

Sample Output:
Email and password are valid. 
Validation process completed.


This is my attempt:
import re
def validate_email(email):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Email cannot be empty")

    pattern = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
    if re.match(pattern, email):
        return True
    return False

def validate_password(password):
    if not password:
        raise ValueError("Password cannot be empty")
    pattern = r"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$"
    if re.match(pattern, password):
        return True
    return False

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            email = input("Enter your email address: ")
            if not validate_email(email):
                print("Invalid email format. Please ensure the email has exactly one '@' and at least one '.' in the domain part.")
                continue
            password = input("Enter your password: ")
            if not validate_password(password):
                print("Invalid password. Please ensure the password is at least 8 characters long and includes at least one digit and one letter.")
                continue
            print("Email and password are valid. Validation process completed.")
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

There are test cases:
TestCase 1:
Purpose: Handling errors and exceptions.
Hint: Ensure your email has exactly one '@' and at least one '.' in the domain part.
TestCase2:
Purpose: Handling errors and exceptions.
Hint: Verify the email's username (before '@') and domain (after '@') are not empty.
TestCase3:
Purpose: Handling errors and exceptions.
Hint: Ensure your password is at least 8 characters long.
TestCase4:
Purpose: Handling errors and exceptions.
Hint: Include at least one digit and one letter in your password.
TestCase5:
Purpose: Handling errors and exceptions.
Hint: Pay attention to the error messages to understand what needs to be corrected.
The test cases 2, 3 and 4 have failed. What is going wrong here?
